# Cycle "for" dosent start

Tags: python-3.x

```
   class AnonymousSurvey():
    def __init__(self, question):
        self.question = question
        self.responses = []

    def show_question(self, question):
        print(question)

    def store_response(self, new_response):
        self.responses.append(new_response)

    def show_results(self):
        for response in self.responses:
            print("Survey results: ")
            print('- ' + response)


question = "What language did you first learn to speak?"
my_survey = AnonymousSurvey(question)

my_survey.show_question(question)
print("Enter 'q' at any yime yo quit. \n")
while True:
    response = input("Languge: ")
    if response == 'q':
        break

my_survey.store_response(response)

print("\nThank's everyone ")
my_survey.show_results()
```

My response in terminal:

```
 What language did you first learn to speak?
 Enter 'q' at any yime yo quit. 

 Languge: Spanish
 Languge: English
 Languge: q

 Thank's everyone 
 Survey results: 
 - q
```

''''''''''''''''In results displayed only value 'q', but i want to displayed values "Spanish", "English". Value 'q' just finish the programm''''''''''''

Comment: You have to use `for response in self.responses`. This way the variable is taken from the class instead of looking in the local function scope.

Comment: I do, but cycle dosent start again

Comment: Displayed, last entered value. But I want to displayed all entered values

Comment: Can you update the question (especially with the proposed edits). Also show what the result currently is, it's hard to help you otherwise

Comment: I edit my question, please help!!!!

Comment: `my_survey.store_response(response)` needs to be indented as @Rizquuula solution requires.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. This made it possible for people to understand what the issue was. The solution @Rizquuula gave is indeed correct! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Fix the placement of your `my_survey.store_response(response)` it should be in the while loop.

Then, the `print("Survey results: ")` should be above the `for` loop

```
class AnonymousSurvey():
    def __init__(self, question):
        self.question = question
        self.responses = []

    def show_question(self, question):
        print(question)

    def store_response(self, new_response):
        self.responses.append(new_response)

    def show_results(self):
        print("Survey results: ")
        for response in self.responses:
            print('- ' + response)


question = "What language did you first learn to speak?"
my_survey = AnonymousSurvey(question)

my_survey.show_question(question)
print("Enter 'q' at any yime yo quit. \n")
while True:
    response = input("Languge: ")
    if response == 'q':
        break
    my_survey.store_response(response)

print("\nThank's everyone ")
my_survey.show_results()
```